# An interface may only extend a class or another interface

Tags: angular, typescript

We are on typescript 2.9.2

I am not able to extend this interface *DropDownOption*. Getting an error "error TS2312: An interface may only extend a class or another interface."

Is there a different way to write this that avoids the use of types perhaps so that it is a pure interface and can be extended?

```
export interface BaseDropdownOption {
  id: string;
}
export interface ValueDropdownOption extends BaseDropdownOption {
  value: string;
  template?: never;
}
export interface TemplateDropdownOption extends BaseDropdownOption {
  template: TemplateRef<any>;
  value?: never;
}
export type DropdownOption = ValueDropdownOption | TemplateDropdownOption;
```

So for example, this code produces the error above:

```
export interface DropdownOptionWithPayload extends DropdownOption {
  payload: any
  name: string
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't extent a union, you could however use an intersection to add properties:

```
export type DropdownOptionExt = DropdownOption & {
  payload: any
  name: string
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
export type DropdownOptionExt = 
     | (ValueDropdownOption & { payload: any; name: string; }) 
     | (TemplateDropdownOption & { payload: any; name: string; })
```

Comment: that isn't exactly the same thing though.

Comment: @robertotomás Depends what you want to achieve. If you want the result to be a type with extra properties on each member of the union, this will achieve that result

Comment: note that the extra properties are mutually exclusive

Comment: @robertotomás that was not mentioned in the question, could you maybe include the type you expect as a result of this extension ?

Comment: in fact, _it is_ in the source code in the original question -- I don't want a type.. at the end of the day, I want an interface. :)

Comment: @robertotomás I see the original `ValueDropdownOption` and `TemplateDropdownOption` that are mutually exclusive .. it is not clear to me how the extra props are mutually exclusive. The intersection keeps the exclusiveness of the original union and adds the extra elements to each member of the original union. Added the resulting type to the answer.

Comment: @robertotomás in this case the difference between a type and an interface is not that important, and unions can't be interfaces.

Comment: this last comment is probably the actual answer ... why can not type unions be interfaces ?

Comment: @robertotomás Design limitation. Interface properties must known when extending, unions don't qualify. But the answer above is good alternative, let me knowif it does not work for you for some reason, I am curios why.,

Comment: @robertotomás Official comment to a similar issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30121